# Class Variables in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm autowiring a repository class into another service class. The repository class has two member variables declared private but not initialized. The values for these member variables are set when one of the methods of the repository class is called during the course of the request. Finally in the service class I'm populating a response object by calling a getter method of the repository class which returns the class variables respectively.

I'm wondering if this is bad practice considering the api will be called by multiple users. But passing the response object as reference to the repository class is a tedious job with the existing design of the code.

The following is the service class where I'm setting PageCount and TotalHits in the DataResponse object. The repository class(userInfoRepositoryV2) is initially called in the first line of the method after which the values for the two class variables are set.

```
public DataResponse getUserInfoV5(String startDate, String endDate, String searchCriteria, RequestType requestType, String userId, Boolean retryable, Integer page, Integer size) throws BadRequestException,EsDataGenerationException {
        FailedUsersV3 failedUsers = userHandler.getUserInfoResponseV5(startDate, endDate, searchCriteria,requestType, userId, retryable, page, size);
        DataResponse dataResponse = new DataResponse();
        dataResponse.setPage(page);
        dataResponse.setPageCount(userInfoRepositoryV2.getPageCount());
        dataResponse.setTotalHits(userInfoRepositoryV2.getTotalHits());
        dataResponse.setData(failedUsers);
        dataResponse.setMeta(new MetaResponse(MetaCodes.SUCCESS.name(), MetaCodes.SUCCESS.getCode(), MetaCodes.SUCCESS.getMessage(), null, null));
        return dataResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is. Never keep state in a singleton (which is what you are doing).

Comment: So the only option is to pass the object as reference and set the field as soon as the variable in initialized right?

Comment: I don't know the design of your code so I cannot advice on that (I'm for hire if you want that ;) ). But as a rule of thumb don't keep state. In the method you show I don't really see shared state, just an object created inside a method. So not sure which member variables you mean (I suspect the `failedUsers` for one).

Comment: DataResponse is the object I want to populate. When I call getUserInfoResponseV5, an instance of userInfoRepository is called which sets the value for the 2 member variables(Page count and Total Hits) of UserInfoRepository. I am then using getters in UserInfoRepository to populate dataResponse with the values of the member variables

Answer (score 0):

yes it is considered a bad practice , saving data inside a singleton will lead to unexpected results when multiple requests are incoming .
without providing more context its hard to advice but usually returning the data in the response of the method of the repository would be the way to go.